# Can't forEach in a JSON file

Tags: json, foreach

i'm trying something, so, I have a JSON file that contains informations about persons, and I want to only get their names (for every persons). But with my code I only get the Users, and I want to have only the names of every users

Here's my JSON file :

```
*file : test.json*
{
    "Users": [{

        "Person1": {
            "name": "User1",
            "age": "20"
        },
        "Person2": {
            "name": "User2",
            "age": "21"
        },
        "Person3": {
            "name": "User3",
            "age": "23"
        }
    }]
}
```

And here's my code :

```
const fichier = require('./test.json');

fichier.Users.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element)
});
```

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake in the JSON file. The array has an extra bracket *{}* that describe there is only one object in it with all person objects identified by a key.

I have removed the extra brackets and refactored the User object removing the "PersonX" key.

Here is the correct JSON data:

```json
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "name": "User1",
            "age": "20"
        },
        {
            "name": "User2",
            "age": "21"
        },
        {
            "name": "User3",
            "age": "23"
        }
    ]
}
```

The javascript code is correct :)